# Noun Phrases and Commas

Tags: noun-phrases

Can Noun phrases include commas?

Example:

> A star for each Kid attending the classes Math, English and History.

Comment: math, English and history classes.

Answer (score 0):

Commas are perfectly fine in noun phrases.

However, this version is not very natural. Better variations include moving *classes* to the end and leaving it out altogether:

> a star for each kid attending the Math, English and History classes
>   a star for each kid attending Math, English and History

Also, the above implies that only those children who attend *all three* will get a star. If what's meant is children who attend *any* of them, then it should be ***or*** rather than ***and***.

Finally note that what's given in the question is not an actual sentence—there is no verb. Which is why I didn't punctuate my examples with a capital letter or period.